# how do I absolute the negative numbers in my list?

Tags: python

hi how do I implement the abs() function in python to ensure that the negative values in my list are now positive and stored to another variable?

say...

```
sample = [-1, -3, 2, 5]
```

and I want the new list of positive values in variable sample1, how then should I do it?

```
sample1 = map(abs, sample)
print(sample1)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us your current attempt?

Comment: have added what I've tried so far

Comment: but I'm not sure how to go about storing the new values into another variable sample1

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sample = [-1, -3, 2, 5]
>>> sample1 = [abs(x) for x in sample]
>>> sample1
[1, 3, 2, 5]
```